# Effect of "decrypting" clear-text then "re-encrypting" it

Tags: encryption, aes

I have a (unique) situation where I receive data that is a combination of encrypted (with AES-CBC) and clear-text blocks and I cannot tell which blocks are encrypted. I plan to decrypt all of the data, *including the clear-text*, I receive and store it locally. Before retransmitting the data, I will encrypt it again. I need the blocks that were originally in clear-text to be in their original clear-text form for the retransmission.

If I decrypt the entire original message, even the blocks that were in clear-text, and then re-encrypt it with AES-CBC and the same key used for decryption, will the originally clear-text blocks be the same after re-encryption as they were when they were received.

Comment: Sounds like you want to know if `E(D(M,K),K) = M)` where `E` is encryption, `D` is  decryption, `M` is the message, and `K` Is the key. Is this correct? Please provide more background to your question, and explain your own research effort.

Comment: Are you asking: When using AES CBC, will encrypting the same clear text with the same key multiple times produce the same encrypted text each time?

Comment: zoran2 - I rewrote your question based on comments you made to my answer. I hopefully made it more accurately represent the problem you are trying to solve. if you disagree with my edits or I somehow made it worse, please feel free to edit the question and fix it

Answer (score 4):

Always encrypting the same text to the same value leads to data leakage, violating [semantic security](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_security). To prevent this, [CBC mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29) uses an [initialization vector (IV)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Initialization_vector). The IV is just a random string of bits equal to the block size of the cipher. This is XORed with the first block of clear-text to be encrypted. This makes the first encrypted block random. Each successive clear-text block is XORed with the cipher text of the previous block so that each block after the first is also random. From the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Cipher_Block_Chaining_.28CBC.29):

[image]

The IV is then stored beside the encrypted text to allow decryption when the process is reversed:
[image]

This use of the IV ensures that encrypting the same message twice will *not* produce the same encrypted text. CBC mode even protects against repetition in a single cipher string. So repeating bytes in the clear-text message will not encrypt to the same byte sequence.

Note that a poorly implemented CBC encryption might reuse IVs and therefore produce the same encrypted text for the same message. See [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/10511/24011) for more information.

Comment: sorry, the prob i have is: i recv data which is encrypted, but some of the data will be clear, i don't get info which block is encr/clear. When receiving: all blocks will be decrypted and stored. Later when sending back stored data just before send i decrypt. My question is: for data rcvd as clear will this always work, will i always send back what was rcvd?

Comment: above should say: later when sending back stored data just before send i _encrypt_. The prob may sound weird but there is actually a reason.

Comment: No, the data a will not be the same because the IV is random. This causes each encryption to produce different encrypted text.

Comment: ok, that't what i thought, then did some tests and it was the same. maybe i get away with it if the IV is i based on the block sequence no/position on the device (may be encr etc before used as an IV but it's not random), just a guess. If IV is random for each blk then it would have to be kept somwhere for each blk, right? i doubt that's done in this case.

Comment: Yes, you need the IV to decrypt. If you are successfully decrypting (ie: getting the correct clear-text), then you have the correct key and IV. Re-encrypting with the same key and IV *will* produce the same encrypted text. So if you are keeping both the same, what you are doing might work. It's hard to be sure without knowing more details.